# Loading NIFTI image using Qt and ITK

Tags: qt4, itk

I am trying to load NIFTI volume images using Qt and ITK.
Could you, please, provide some sample code for this issue?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(
    this, tr("Open File"), "C:\\", tr("NIFTI Images (*.nii *.nii.gz *.hdr)"));
if (fileName.isNull()) //user cancelled
    return;

typedef itk::Image< short, 3 > ImageType;
typedef itk::ImageFileReader<ImageType> ReaderType;
ReaderType::Pointer reader = ReaderType::New();
reader->SetFileName(fileName.toStdString());
reader->Update();
ImageType::Pointer image=reader->GetOutput();
```